# Reflect metadata design:paramtypes return an array with unfedined element

Tags: node.js, typescript, reflect-metadata

I'm trying to obtain the constructor arguments for some class but the <> get an array with a undefined element.

For the test I work with services Example2Services and ExampleService

Example2Service.ts

```
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';


   export class Example2Service {
      constructor(private es1: ExampleService) {}

      getValue() {
        return "some value2";
      }
    }
```

ExampleService.ts

```
import { Example2Service } from './example2.service';

export class ExampleService {
    constructor(private es2: Example2Service) {    }

    getValue() {
        return this.es2.getValue();
    }
    getString() {
        return "1"
    }
}
```

In this function I send a Example2Service

```
private resolve(target: Type): Object | Function {

    let tokens = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target) 
    ...
}
```

debugging the code, I get this for the token variable

[image]

trying to understand the behavior, I try to obtain the args directly from some classes

```
import {Example2Service} from '../../exaple2.service.ts';
import {ExampleService} from '../../exaple.service.ts';

private resolve(target: Type): Object | Function {

    let tokensA = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', Example2Service)
    let tokensB = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', ExampleService);
    let tokens = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target);
    ...
}
```

debuging this case I get this, sending a Example2Service to resolve function. Now tokens is an array with an Class inside. Note that when importing the Example2Service and ExampleService this happened, but when changing the import order the behavior changes

[image]

---

### EDIT

I found out that this occurs when there is circularity between dependencies